# Conditional modifiers with #available not executing correctly

Tags: swiftui

I've got a custom modifier to replace navigation bar title with an image view, in iOS 14 this is pretty straightforward with the .toolbar modifier, however in iOS 13 it needs a bit more work but it's possible.

The problem comes when I want to use both solutions in a conditional modifier, the following code reproduces the issue, it works when running on iOS 14 but it produces no result on iOS 13, however if the "#available" condition is removed from the modifier leaving only iOS 13 code, it works as expected. Wrapping iOS 14 in AnyView does not help either:

```
    extension View {
        @ViewBuilder
        func configuresIcon() -> some View {
            if #available(iOS 14.0, *){
                self.modifier(NavigationConfigurationView14Modifier())
            } else {
                self.modifier(NavigationConfigurationViewModifier(configure: { nv in
                    nv.topItem?.titleView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: IMAGE_NAME_HERE))
                }))
            }
        }
    }
    
    
    struct NavigationConfigurationViewModifier: ViewModifier {
        let configure: (UINavigationBar) -> ()
        
        func body(content: Content) -> some View {
            content.background(NavigationControllerLayout(configure: {
                configure($0.navigationBar)
            }))
        }
    }
    
    @available(iOS 14.0, *)
    struct NavigationConfigurationView14Modifier: ViewModifier {
        func body(content: Content) -> some View {
            content
                .toolbar {
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) {
                        Image(IMAGE_NAME_HERE)
                    }
                }
        }
    }

    struct NavigationControllerLayout: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
        var configure: (UINavigationController) -> () = { _ in }
        
        func makeUIViewController(
            context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<NavigationControllerLayout>
        ) -> UIViewController {
            UIViewController()
        }
        
        func updateUIViewController(
            _ uiViewController: UIViewController,
            context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<NavigationControllerLayout>
        ) {
            if let navigationContoller = uiViewController.navigationController {
                configure(navigationContoller)
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap content in `Group` (not tested - only idea)

```
extension View {
    @ViewBuilder
    func configuresIcon() -> some View {
      Group {
        if #available(iOS 14.0, *){
            self.modifier(NavigationConfigurationView14Modifier())
        } else {
            self.modifier(NavigationConfigurationViewModifier(configure: { nv in
                nv.topItem?.titleView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: IMAGE_NAME_HERE))
            }))
        }
     }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it will work if we check OS version at runtime, not at compiletime (because `buildlimitedavailability(_:)` is itself [available only since iOS 14](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/viewbuilder/buildlimitedavailability(_:))).

```
 extension View {
    func erase() -> AnyView {
        return AnyView(self)
    }
    func applyIf<VM1: ViewModifier, VM2: ViewModifier>(_ condition: @autoclosure () -> Bool, ApplyIfTrue: VM1, ApplyIfFalse: VM2
) -> AnyView {
         if condition() {
            return self.modifier(ApplyIfTrue).erase()
         } else {
            return self.modifier(ApplyIfFalse).erase()
         }
     }
    
    @ViewBuilder func configuresIcon() -> some View {
        self.applyIf(NSProcessInfo().isOperatingSystemAtLeastVersion(NSOperatingSystemVersion(majorVersion: 14, minorVersion: 0, patchVersion: 0)),
                     ApplyIfTrue: NavigationConfigurationView14Modifier(),
                     ApplyIfFalse: modifier(NavigationConfigurationViewModifier(configure: { nv in
                        nv.topItem?.titleView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: IMAGE_NAME_HERE))
                     })))
       }
 }
```

If you really need `#available` option there are several things to try. 1) Maybe it is because of inappropriate extension point, so try to move it out of `View`'s extension. 2)Move the logic from modifiers to the body.

For example the code below work fine.

```
@available(macOS 10.15, iOS 13.0, *)
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            if #available(macOS 11.0, iOS 14.0, *) {
                LazyVStack {
                    ForEach(1...1000, id: \.self) { value in
                        Text("Row \(value)")
                    }
                }
            } else {
                VStack {
                    ForEach(1...1000, id: \.self) { value in
                        Text("Row \(value)")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```